# used wrapper but modal not opening

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import Dialog from 'material-ui/Dialog';

    export default class simpleModal extends React.Component {

        constructor(props){
          super(props)
        }

        handlePrimaryButton = () => {
          this.props.router.push('/some/path');
        }

        render(){
          return(
              <Dialog
                actions={<RaisedButton
                  label="OK"
                  primary={true}
                  onTouchTap={this.handlePrimaryButton}
                />}
                modal={false}
                open={this.props.open}
              >
                {this.props.msg}
              </Dialog>
          )
        }
    }
```

I created a wrapper using material-ui Dialog component but I can't open it. In another component I have this in my render method:

`<simpleModal open={this.state.openSimpleModal} />`

I then change the state of `openSimpleModal` using `this.setState({openSimpleModal: true})`

I don't see the modal being open. Is there anything missing in my above code? I manage to use `Dialog` component of material-ui directly but not with a wrapper.

Note: No error in chrome console at all.

Comment: check your Javascript console in your webtool developper kit ;) ( F12 )

Comment: @Alex no error there, sorry forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but I had the same issue while using a wrapper. Had to use a callback to the parent, not pretty.

The Dialog component in material-ui-next doesn't have this issue any more.